# Can not import svelte component into +layout.svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I just tried to experiment with sveltekit but I already fail at the very beginning trying to create a navbar component and import it into my layout.

From what I understand from the documentation, I only have to create the component like navbar.svelte and them import it into my +layout.svelte file.

When I do this, I get the following error tho

this is my navbar component

```html
<nav>
    <h4>Navbar Component</h4>
</nav>
```

this is my layout component

```html
<script lang=ts>
 import Navbar from "src/lib/components/ui/navbar.svelte";

</script>
<header>
    <Navbar/>
</header>
<main>
    <slot/>
</main>
<footer>
    <p>footer content</p>
</footer>
```

The compiler gives the following error even tho the file exists, it even auto imported.

**[vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "src/lib/components/ui/navbar.svelte" from "src\routes+layout.svelte". Does the file exist?**

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`$lib` alias](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$lib) to access the files in your `lib` directory.

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import Navbar from "$lib/components/ui/navbar.svelte";
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, I am sorry seems like it was just bugged and I had to restart the dev server :S